# C equivalent of Python format method

Tags: c, function, string-formatting

let me say at first I'm completely aware of `sprintf` and `printf` in C, But they don't meet what I need.

What I want is something like a function which does **return** formatted string and its parameters are just like `printf`. e.g.:
`char *formatted = format("%c%s Mund%c!", '¡', "Hola", 'o');`

Has C a built-in function like that? or it should be implemented by hand?
If the latter, How to implement such function?

It is worth noting that:

1. string length is unknown
2. I don't want to print the string

As a side note: I'll not use c++, and I use mingw-64 gcc

Comment: What is wrong with sprintf ?

Comment: returning means allocating memory or filling a buffer (or returning a static buffer like `strtok` which is dangerous) . `sprintf` takes the "output value" as first argument: a properly sized output buffer. You could wrap `snprintf` and return an allocated string

Comment: Just a suggestion - stop looking for Python "alternatives" in C. There are very few. C is a much lower level language than Python, and has a very limited set of "convenience" features.

Comment: If you would like an easy library (third-party) to do so, [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).

Comment: @YvesDaoust `sprintf` DON'T return the value but change the passed variable. If I don't mind that, it's an antipattern or at least, a dangerous work, and it causes 2 more lines of code, so dirtier code; I don't the length!! - And you can't pass a pointer, because if passed by reference, it's a double pointer, and otherwise, sprintf won't change the argument, unlike the fact `name` = `&name[0]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre My English isn't good & google translator is very unclear & worse, so I can't understand the last sentence

Comment: An antipattern ? A dangerous work ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust probably it's not an antipattern, but if we trust the function, a pointer may be passed to the function, so it causes some errors, but the biggest problem is the unknown length of string.

Comment: `snprintf` can limit the string written. Again, as I said previously - C is not Python. It is a "dangerous" language, it does not offer memory or type safety.

Comment: You cannot know the length of the output without performing the formatting "in a dry run". Code is dangerous when you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: "a pointer may be passed to the function, so it causes some errors": what ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust But the problem is that I don't know the length of input(first parameters)

Comment: You cannot know the length of the output without performing the formatting "in a dry run".

Comment: @YvesDaoust I admit I was wrong,

Comment: So the simplest way is with snprintf. It was designed for this purpose. Alternatively, output to the null device.

Comment: You could try `vasprintf()` or `asprintf()` Or construct them yourself using `[v]snprintf()` and `malloc()`

Comment: This point has been made already, but it's worth repeating: C and Python are very, very different languages.  C is *minimal*, and it was designed to be that way, no one apologizes for it, it's why C was as successful as it was.  Contrariwise, Python is decidedly maximal, and there's a reason that [xkcd 353](http://xkcd.com/353/) was written about it.  C gives you low-level tools and expects you to work with them.  If you expect C to give you high-level tools on a silver platter, you will almost always be disappointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent function unless you make one yourself because, unlike python, strings in C are simple arrays and it's **you** who is responsible for allocating as much memory as you need, passing a pointer to a function, and freeing it later. That's why in functions like sprintf you need to specify an output array (and optionally a `size` value in variants like snprintf).

A custom implementation would be something like this (not including error checks to keep things simple):

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define STRSIZE 256

char* my_sprintf(const char* fmt, ...) {
    /* Create a temporary buffer */
    char temp[STRSIZE];
    /* Get variadic arguments */
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    /* Use the variadic argument variant of snprintf
     * The return value is the number of characters that would have been written,
     * if the buffer was sufficiently large. We use this to determine if we
     * need to repeat on a larger buffer to account for strings of any length */
    int len = vsnprintf(result, STRSIZE, fmt, args);
    /* Cleanup */
    va_end(args);
    /* If the entire string fits in the temp buffer, return a copy */
    if (len < STRSIZE)
        return strdup(temp);
    /* Otherwise, allocate enough memory and repeat */
    char* result = (char*)malloc(len + 1); // +1 for the null terminator
    /* The variadic argument pack is consumed already, so recreate it */
    va_start(args, fmt);
    /* Use the variadic argument variant of sprintf
     * (we already have enough allocated memory now, so no need for snprintf) */
    vsprintf(result, fmt, args);
    /* Cleanup */
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}
```

When you're done, don't forget to free the returned pointer!

```c
char* my_string = my_sprintf("My %s", "format");
...
free(my_string);
```

Comment: The is no need to perform the first allocation.

Comment: Why? I return a pointer so the memory _must_ be allocated.

Comment: Right, the second time.

Comment: When the return value of vsnprintf is larger than or equal to the size **n** that I have allocated then I need to allocate more memory because the original string is truncated to n-1 characters.

Comment: Check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf): "If bufsz is zero, nothing is written and buffer may be a null pointer, however the return value (number of bytes that would be written not including the null terminator) is still calculated and returned."

Comment: So you suggest running snprintf once to calculate the length, perform one allocation and then run sprintf again to get the string? I've seen this before but I've always wondered if it's a better approach because you always run sprintf twice every time to get a result.

Comment: @chqrlie  Re: "Why not use snprintf" --> how would `my_sprintf()` call `snprintf()`?

Comment: typo. I meant why not use `vsnprintf` both times and avoid linking `vsprintf`? Calling `vsprintf` with an arbitrary format string seems a bad idea even if you have computed the formatted string length with a previous call to `vsnprintf`.

Comment: guard3, "always run sprintf twice every time to get a result." --> true, yet with this answer's approach, the smallest allocated string is 128 - high overhead for small strings.  @chqrlie Idea is good: use a local `char` array and if big enough, copy to a right-sized allocated array.

Comment: Seems difficult to find a good compromise. When the output is long, a pre-malloc risks to be insufficient, but formatting twice is costly. :-(

Comment: @chqrlie OK so typo in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115799/c-equivalent-of-python-format-mthod#comment125713542_71116338).  Note that code does not call with `vsprintf` with an _arbitrary_ format string.  It is the same format and supposedly the same stable data (and same locale) as before.  (Passing a `volatile char *` to `"%s"` is UB even on a single call) True strange things happen and calling with `vsnprintf()` does afford some safety.  IAC, answer here is missing errors checks on allocation of printing failures yet the overall idea is sound.

Comment: @chqrlie: yep, this seems a better way.

Comment: @chqrlie et all, `*printf()` has environmental limits like "The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least 4095." so once we are trying to handle huge strings we are already off into the danger zone.  Rather than over language lawyering, be [reasonable and prudent](https://i0.wp.com/truthvoice.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/186lzd4j8zkp5jpg.jpg?fit=300%2C169&ssl=1).  I like 256 or `BUFSIZE`, whichever is smaller.

Comment: More counter-examples with common `printf` extensions: `%m` formats the string obtained from `strerror(errno)`, which may change as you do not preserve `errno` across the call to `realloc()`. Similarly, handlers registered via `register_printf_specifier` on GNU Libc are not guaranteed to produce the same output every time.

Comment: @chqrlie Worth noting `"%m"` is not part of the C standard library, yet still a reasonable example of non-stable print results.

Comment: @chux: hence the initial disclaimer: *common `printf` extensions*.

Comment: @chqrlie included your idea of returning a copy with strdup, I liked it. And fixed const char* return type, silly me! :)

Comment: I'd remove the cast on the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: @guard3: almost perfect! to avoid undefined behavior, you should test for `malloc()` failure and use `vsnprintf()` instead of `vsprintf()`.

Comment: @guard3: another fix: if `len` is negative, you should return `NULL`. This can occur for example in case of encoding errors.

Answer (score 1):

[@guard3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71116338/2410359) approach with clean-up.

Try printing to a local buf and duplicate it.
Otherwise allocate to the reported size needed.
Check for errors along the way.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define MY_APRINTF_BUF_SZ 256
#define MY_APRINTF_TRIES 3 // 2 or more

char* my_aprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
  va_list args;
  char buf_local[MY_APRINTF_BUF_SZ];
  char *buf = buf_local;
  size_t buf_size = sizeof buf_local;

  // Try a few times.
  // Often the 1st time with a local buffer will be good enough for common sized strings
  // Otherwise it "should" work on the 2nd time.
  // Some corner cases may require more tries.
  // Give up after a while.
  for (int i = 0; i < MY_APRINTF_TRIES; i++) {
    va_start(args, fmt);  // TBD: Review if va_copy better/required
    int length_needed = vsnprintf(buf, buf_size, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    // If encoded error occurred ...
    if (length_needed < 0) {
      if (buf == buf_local) {
        return NULL;
      }
      break;
    }
    size_t size_needed = (unsigned) length_needed + 1u;

    if (size_needed <= buf_size) {
      if (buf == buf_local) { // First time
        buf = strdup(buf);  // Code your own my_strdup if strdup not available.
      }
      return buf;
    }
    if (buf == buf_local) {
      buf = NULL;
    }

    // Get more memory
    void *ptr = realloc(buf, size_needed);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
      break;
    }
    buf = ptr;
    buf_size = size_needed;
  }

  // Give up
  free(buf);
  return NULL;
}
```

Sample usage

```
int main() {
  char *s = my_aprintf("%d %s\n", 42, "Hello world!");
  if (s) {
    puts(s);
    free(s);
  }
}
```

If needed

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Use as needed
char *my_strdup(const char *buf) {
  size_t size = strlen(buf) + 1u;
  char *s = malloc(size);
  if (s) {
    memcpy(s, buf, size);
  } else {
#ifdef ENOMEM
    errno = ENOMEM;
#endif
  }
  return s;
 }
```

Comment: More importantly: 1. `void *ptr = realloc(buf, size_needed);` will cause undefined behavior when `buf` still points to `buf_local`. You should add `if (buf == buf_local) buf = NULL;`. 2. you could just `break` from the loop in case of `realloc()` failure. 3. Moving the `if (buf != buf_local) free(buf);` outside the loop would allow for a common error return path by breaking from the loop.  4. You should read `errno` before the loop and set it back to the original value after each successful reallocation.

Comment: @chqrlie 1) Yes - of course.  I had the needed test in there, but lost it in an edit  2,3) Good idea.  4) `errno` is not specified by C to get set on an allocation failure.  IMO, best to let calling code set `errno` to 0 anyways.

Comment: The purpose of saving and restoring `errno` is to make the non-standard `%m` extension behave as expected, ie: produce the same output repeatedly. This should not have any adverse side effects. C does not specify what happens to `errno` in case of success, one of the system calls issued by `malloc()` might set `errno` even if `malloc()` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with:

```
'¡'
```

This is *not* a single `char`. It is a UTF-8 character that occupies *two* `char`. In hex, it is:

```
'\xC2\xA1'
```

Or, depending upon endianness:

```
'\xA1\xC2'
```

The `%c` format will *not* handle this well. You want to use double quotes so it is a *string* and use `%s`.

---

The simple way is to pass down the buffer:

**Edit:** Adjusted to add a buffer length.

```
char *
generate(char *buf,size_t siz)
{

    snprintf(buf,siz,"%s%s Mund%c!","¡", "Hola", 'o');
    buf[siz - 1] = 0;

    return buf;
}
```

---

Closer to what you want is to allocate the result:

```
char *
generate(void)
{
    char buf[1000];

    snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"%s%s Mund%c!","¡", "Hola", 'o');
    buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = 0;

    char *format = strdup(buf);

    return format;
}
```

---

Note that `c` does *not* have automatic free/garbage collection, so for this second example, the *caller* will have to do (e.g):

```
char *formatted = generate();

// do stuff with formatted ...

// free the result when no longer needed ...
free(formatted);
```

Comment: Your first generate has a parameter declared as `char buf[1000]`. It's a pointer to char. `sizeof(buf)` will return 4 or 8 based on whether you are compiling for 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: Moreover `buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = 0;` is definitely wrong. Maybe `strlen` instead of `sizeof`?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Okay, so I fixed the first example. But, in the second, `sizeof(buf) - 1` is the correct safety to use. More for `strncpy` but harmless otherwise. For that, if the buffer is too short, using `strlen` on the output of `strncpy` is UB.

Comment: Check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf): [snprintf] Writes the results to a character string buffer. At most bufsz - 1 characters are written. The resulting character string will be terminated with a null character, unless bufsz is zero. There's no need to add a terminator.